# R Data.table error when creating a new column

Tags: r, data.table

on the below code, Data.table is throwing an error when i try to create new columns. May i know how to get through this error. I believe its the problem with the syntax as I'm still a beginner in R.
I have read online sources where adding a by argument would resolve but im not sure how to add it.

```
NF = MFDETAILED[,c(1,2)]
  
  feature_names = colnames(compare)
  NF = cbind(NF, data.table( NF = apply(compare,1,function(x {paste0(feature_names[(which(x[]==1))],collapse = ", ")}), NMF = apply(compare,1,function(x) {paste0(feature_names[(which(x[]==0))],collapse = ", ")})))
#ERROR LINE
  **NF[, c("LOOKUP", "MAT") := tstrsplit(COMBINATION, "-", fixed=TRUE)]**
  NF[, ("COMBINATION"):=NULL]
  setcolorder(NF, c( "LOOKUP","MAT","MS", "NF","NMF"))
  setnames(NF,c("LOOKUP MATERIAL", "MATERIAL", "MATCH SCORE","MATCH FEATURES","NON MATCH FEATURES"))
```

Error message:-
Error in `[.data.table`(NF, , `:=`(c("LOOKUP", "MAT"), tstrsplit(COMBINATION,  :  Supplied 2 columns to be assigned 4 items. Please see NEWS for v1.12.2.

Comment: Your code line with the `apply` calls looks very inefficient. Anyway, we cannot be sure without a reproducible example but if looks like `tstrsplit` gives you four columns and not two. Check `NF[, tstrsplit(COMBINATION, "-", fixed=TRUE)]`.

Comment: Will this syntax works? NF[, c("LOOKUP", "MAT") := tstrsplit(COMBINATION, "-", fixed=TRUE),by = .(COMBINATION)]. I have used a by argument

Comment: I think it's a syntax error and you forgot to close a bracket in the anonymous function. Try:  "NF = cbind(NF, data.table( NF = apply(compare,1,function(x) {paste0(feature_names[(which(x[]==1))],collapse = ", ")}), NMF = apply(compare,1,function(x) {paste0(feature_names[(which(x[]==0))],collapse = ", ")})))"

Comment: Thank you. But do you think that adding by argument in the syntax will resolve the issue as the error suggests that. This link explains about that https://stackoverflow.com/q/67091535/6537892

Comment: If you don't provide sample data, there's not a lot we can do to really answer that question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you. Adding a by argument to the tstrsplit function resolved the issue.`NF[, c("LOOKUP", "MAT") := tstrsplit(COMBINATION, "-", fixed=TRUE),by = .(COMBINATION)]`

Answer (score 0):

First up, get an example dataset:

```
library(data.table)
dt_main <- data.table(fruits=c("Pears Bananas Grapefruit", "Apples Oranges Kiwi"))
```

You are using `tstrsplit()` too split a variable into multiple values. Look at what happens, without assignment - I get three variables:

```
> dt_main[, tstrsplit(fruits, " ")]
#        V1      V2         V3
# 1:  Pears Bananas Grapefruit
# 2: Apples Oranges       Kiwi
```

It created two variables. You are doing this, and then trying to assign those values to too few variables:

```
dt_main[, c("fruit_1", "fruit_2") := tstrsplit(fruits, " ")]
# Error in `[.data.table`(dt_main, , `:=`(c("fruit_1", "fruit_2"), tstrsplit(fruits,  : 
#   Supplied 2 columns to be assigned 3 items. Please see NEWS for v1.12.2.
```

**You need as many variables to be initiated as you are trying to assign:**

```
# dt_main[, c("fruit_1", "fruit_2", "fruit_3") := tstrsplit(fruits, " ")][]
                             fruits   fruit_1   fruit_2      fruit_3
# 1:       Pears Bananas Grapefruit     Pears   Bananas   Grapefruit
# 2:            Apples Oranges Kiwi    Apples   Oranges         Kiwi
```

*PS. The problem is very clearly explained in the error message, you really should have put in a bit of effort to a) find the solution yourself and b) make a reproducible example. Please do so in the future.*